# Make MATLAB accept KeyPress only once

Tags: matlab, key, response

I am currently trying to write an experiment in MATLAB. As part of it, it should accept and record a key response, either 1 or 0. The problem is that I only need the keys to be recorded at one specific time slot, and to be ignored in the other parts of the experiment. The response has to be recorded along with the time it took to respond, and it should be done once only, the earliest (so that once the user has pressed a key, the program does not record the subsequent ones).

So far, I have attempted numerous ways. These are probably nooby workarounds, but I am not good with object oriented programming.

One option is to use

```
set(gcf,'KeyPressFcn',@KeyDownListener)
```

where KeyDownListener is

```
function KeyUpListener(key_hand, key_obj, starting_time)

     toc(starting_time)
     key_pressed = key_obj.Key; return; end
```

However, there are two problems: 1) I am struggling trying to get the value from this function back to the calling script; 2) Once MATLAB reads this `set(...)` piece of code, it keeps capturing every single key pressed. So, basically, if there are 100 trials (each consisting of, say, 5 stages, of which the keypress should only be accepted at stage 4) in the experiment put in a loop, the `set(...)` will be ignored at the first run at stages 1-3 before it first appears, but will then be present in all the runs from the second, at every stage, 1-5.

Then I tried to put both the calling script and the called function into another function called from an outer script, so that once the control is returned to that higher level script, I put in another

```
set(gcf,'KeyPressFcn',@mute)
```

by which `mute` function performs no actions whatsoever. This seems to work for problem No 2, but it still does not allow me to obtain the value for the keypress callback, and, as I am using `pause(..)` to allow the user time for response, it does not interrupt with the first key pressed, it waits for the entire time allocated in the brackets for `pause`.

Comment: could you please provide a minimal working example? i feel like `pause` wont be the right way here. how about setting a variable that allows the key capturing and is turned on only in the given stages

Comment: @Finn Hello Finn! Either I am not a particularly inventuous with the algorithms, or it is not really convenient to do it without 'pause', as otherwise it will need to launch several 'timer' functions. I tend to get messed up with the timers,  so I try to keep them to the minimum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Passing variable around:

I recommend using [`setappdata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and [`getappdata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) to pass variables around between callbacks of a GUI.
You can also read [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) for more informations about this aspect.

### Assigning and disabling callbacks:

To disable a callback function, you do not need to re-assign the callback to a function that does nothing, you can simply assign an empty array:

```
% assign the 'KeyDownListener' function and pass one parameter ('var1') with it
set( h.fig, 'KeyPressFcn',{@KeyDownListener,var1}) 

% then later when you don't need it anymore:
% Disable the 'KeyPressFcn listener, assign 'empty' to it
set( h.fig, 'KeyPressFcn',[])
```

---

### Full example:

Below is a minimal GUI which demonstrate how to capture a single key press (and the time), then save the data collected into the `appdata` space of the application, where they are collected again by a 'display' function (where you could also do whatever you want with the data collected).

code for `SingleKeyPressDemo.m`:

```
function h = SingleKeyPressDemo

% create a minimal figure with a button and 2 text fields
h.fig = figure ;
h.btn = uicontrol('Style','Pushbutton','String','Start capture',...
                  'units','Normalized','Position',[0.1 0.6 0.8 0.3],...
                  'Callback',@StartKeyCapture) ;
h.txtKey = uicontrol('Style','text','String','Key pressed:',...
                  'units','Normalized','Position',[0.1 0.4 0.8 0.1]) ;
h.txtTime = uicontrol('Style','text','String','Elapsed time:',...
                  'units','Normalized','Position',[0.1 0.3 0.8 0.1]) ;

% assign a callback to the KeyRelease event to intercept passing the
% eventdata to the command window
set(h.fig,'KeyReleaseFcn',@KeyReleased)

% initialise appdata variables to hold the captured key and the time
setappdata( h.fig , 'CapturedKey' , [] )
setappdata( h.fig , 'Elapsed_time' , [] )

% save the handle structure
guidata( h.fig , h)


function StartKeyCapture(hobj,~)
    h = guidata( hobj ) ;   % retrieve the handle structure
    StartTime = tic ;       % Start a stopwatch

    % assigne the callback funtion, passing the stopwatch in parameter
    set(h.fig,'KeyPressFcn',{@KeyDownListener,StartTime})

    % disable the button until a key is pressed (also makes it loose the
    % focus, which is handy otherwise the button keeps the focus and hides
    % the 'KeyPressedFcn'
    set( h.btn , 'Enable','off')


function KeyDownListener(hobj, key_obj, starting_time)
    % Detect key pressed and time elapsed
    Elapsed_time = toc(starting_time) ;
    key_pressed = key_obj.Key;

    h = guidata( hobj ) ;                                   % retrieve the handle structure
    setappdata( h.fig , 'CapturedKey' , key_pressed ) ;     % save the captured key
    setappdata( h.fig , 'Elapsed_time' , Elapsed_time ) ;   % save the elapsed time


    set(h.fig,'KeyPressFcn',[]) % remove listener so new key press will not trigger execution
    set( h.btn , 'Enable','on') % re-enable the button for a new experiment

    % (optional) do something after a key was pressed
    display_results(h.fig) ;


function display_results(hobj)
    h = guidata( hobj ) ;   % retrieve the handle structure

    % retrieve the saved data
    CapturedKey  = getappdata( h.fig , 'CapturedKey' ) ;
    Elapsed_time = getappdata( h.fig , 'Elapsed_time' ) ;

    % update display
    set( h.txtKey  , 'String', sprintf('Key pressed: %s',CapturedKey) ) ;
    set( h.txtTime , 'String', sprintf('Elapsed time: %f ms',Elapsed_time) ) ;

function  KeyReleased(~,~)
% do nothing
% The only purpose of this function is to intercept the KeyReleased event
% so it won't be automatically passed on to the command window.
```

Creating GUI programmatically is full of verbose in Matlab, focus on the code in the 2 functions `StartKeyCapture` and `KeyDownListener` to achieve what you were asking.

This example will produce the following GUI:

[image]

---

### Additional note:

I would also recommend against the use of `gcf` in a GUI application. It is a handy shortcut when debugging or working in the console with figures opened around, but in a GUI the calls to its own elements should be as self-contained as possible. MATLAB offers way to save the handles of all your GUI elements (all the uicontrols, including the main figure), so you can call them *explicitely* when you need them. This reduces the risk of errors (imagine your user is also running other figures in the same MATLAB session, if your callback triggers and call `gcf` when the user was fiddling with another figure, you are going to try to execute code on a different figure than it was intended to ... which can easily result in errors).

Read the documentation on [`guidata`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) for more information (and/or observe how I've used it in the example above).

---

### Edit:

To avoid the focus coming back to the command window at every key pressed, you also have to also define a callback function to the corresponding `KeyRelease` event, otherwise the event will automatically be forwarded to the command window (which will take the focus).

A clean way to do is to simply add callback assignment

```
set(h.fig,'KeyReleaseFcn',@KeyReleased)
```

once and for all in the figure definition (you don't have to set/undo this callback at each experiment), and then define an empty function `function KeyReleased(~,~)` which does nothing. This way is implemented in the modified code example above.

Another way to do without the extra empty function, would be to simply define the callback in line at the assignment time:

```
set(h.fig,'KeyReleaseFcn','disp([])')
```

This way you do not need to have an empty `KeyReleased` function.

Note however that a callback function **must** be defined (either inline or later in the code). Simply assigning `empty` to the callback will not work. (e.g. both options below will fail to intercept the event and will forward it to the command window:

```
set(h.fig,'KeyReleaseFcn','') % not working
set(h.fig,'KeyReleaseFcn',[]) % not working either
```

Comment: @ Hoki Thank you! I am not yet sure if it works, as it is a part of the bigger thing, but part of it is definetely what I need. There is one small nuance, however. When I press a key, the focus always goes away from window, and passes to the command line. Could you kindly suggest a way to make focus remain on window?

Comment: @CASUS_BELLI, I've modified the answer to prevent the command window to take the focus.